# omnet++ problem with simple project run (tiktok)

Tags: omnet++

I'm beginner in OMNeT++ and I wrote a simple project and run it with OMNeT++. I got the following error:

> Class "my_node" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel() -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) CDN (id=1), during network setup

I created an other project and wrote this again and also get that error. My c++ code is the following:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

class CDNClass : public cSimpleModule
{
protected:
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

Define_Module(CDNClass);

void CDNClass::initialize(){
  if (strcmp("note1",getName())==0) {
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("data");
        send(msg, "out");
   }
}

void CDNClass::handleMessage(cMessage *msg){
   send(msg,"out");
}
```

And my ned file is:

```
package proje_shabake;

//
// TODO auto-generated type
//
simple my_node
    {
        gates:
            input in;
            output out;
    }
network CDN
{
submodules:
    node1: my_node {
        @display("p=40,54");
    }
    node2: my_node {
        @display("p=158,62");
    }
connections:
    node1.out --> node2.in;
    node2.out --> node1.in;
}
```

Also my ini file is:

```
[General]
network = CDN
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default OMNeT++ expects that C++ class of a simple module has the same name as the name of the simple module in NED.
The name of your simple module is `my_node`, so the C++ class `my_node` is expected. However, in your code there is no that class.
I suggest changing in your C++ code all instance of `CDNClass` with `my_node`.

By the way: in OMNeT++ there is an option to generate all files required by a simple module in a few steps. Choose `File` | `New` | `Simple Module`.